# Magento2 Fatal Error: Call to a member function isStatic() on boolean

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am getting

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function isStatic() on boolean

```
This error in addAttributeToSelect() function on module-eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection.php on line 480
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a corrupted attribute data.
I suppressed the attribute in question and I recreated it and the problem disappear for me.

Comment: Can you please share more details regarding suppressing attributes?